# Image validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I used laravel "image" validation rule to check if uploaded file is image,
do I require to also use `file()->isValid()` to check if the image is uploaded correctly or is it a redundant step?

Comment: So long as you use the built in Laravel validation to ensure its an image, it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

use to this code for image validation in laravel.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
     'picture' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png | max:1000'
]);
```